# Integrating Paypal Login in Rails app not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, paypal, single-sign-on, omniauth

I'm trying to integrate Paypal login within my Rails app and I can't make it work.

I was following the guide: http://cristianobetta.com/blog/2013/09/27/integrating-login-with-paypal-into-rails/

I created an application from the paypal developer site, and set the followings:

- App return URL (test): http:/ /localhost:3000/auth/paypal/callback
- App return URL (live): http:/ /localhost:3000/auth/paypal/callback

and I get the error:

"Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request does not match with the registered redirect_uri. Please check the request."

when I try to visit the URL:

http:/ /localhost:3000/auth/paypal

Interesting enough, I get the same error if I input my application credential in the official Paypal API integration tool:

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/ruby?interactive=ON&env=sandbox

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The url `http://localhost:3000` is unreachable from outside your computer.  You're going to have to set up hosting if you want to test this.

Comment: Its your local browser that must reach the URL, so localhost is fine in theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set this value inside of your sandbox application on the developer website.

- Log into [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com)
- Click Applications
- Under My Rest Apps click your App name
- Click Edit next to App redirect URLs
- Set the return URLs for live or test
- Save

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply Aaron, I just updated my question with the URL I'm currently using as redirect URLs:

- App return URL (test): http:/ /localhost:3000/auth/paypal/callback 
- App return URL (live): http:/ /localhost:3000/auth/paypal/callback

Is it the case that I can't set the return URLs to my local environment?

Comment: Normally you also need to pass the return url in the setup of the auth token as well. when I do it with javascript I am required to pass my appid, returnurl, and scopes.

Comment: Also, I changed my uri to localhost and it works fine as long as I am appending it to the request url: `&redirect_uri=http://localhost/login/`

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer? The question states that these steps have been taken. What is the real answer here?

Answer (score 3):

This has changed a bit since the accepted answer, and will presumably change again soon... but here's how you do this now.

- Log into developer.paypal.com
- Click on Dashboard (https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications)
- Click your app name under "Rest API Apps"
- Scroll to the box at the bottom of the screen labeled "Sandbox (or Live) App Settings
- Set the **Return URL** (Where users will be redirected after test transactions)
- Click save

**NOTE**

This Return URL must exactly match the **redirect_uri** that you pass in via querystring (so it's confusing as to why you'd need to pass it in in the first place)

**GOTCHA**

At this point in time, the **Return URL** can seemingly never be updated. In my recent experience, if you don't type it correctly the first time you save it, you will have to create a new app.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that gotcha! I lost an hour to that because I accidentally set the redirect to a non-secure uri, and I couldn't understand why it was failing with a redirect error after I changed the redirect.

Comment: Nitrous users, setting the Return URL like this worked for me: `http://ruby-on-rails-1xxxx3.nitrousapp.com:3000/auth/paypal/callback`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by setting both the live and test redirect URLs to the same thing.

Plus, I ensured that I ticked to get Personal Information from the advanced settings panel, also adding URLs for privacy and agreement links.

The portal hung when set to localhost addresses for those links, so possibly PayPal tried to dereference them, so I put in real fake URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this issue myself, albeit in a Sinatra rather than Rails app - like you, I was using `http://localhost:4567/auth/paypal/callback` as the return URL - changing it to `http://127.0.0.1:4567/auth/paypal/callback` on the PayPal dev portal and accessing my app from 127.0.0.1 rather than localhost fixed it for me.

Comment: See @broox's answer as he has a **very** interesting gotcha!  I think originally I set up my entry as `127.0.0.1:4567` and "changed" it to `localhost:4567`.